# I have created a docker image for python PyQt4 application using ubuntu 14.04 ,now when i run container i wan to access docker host ip and interfaces

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-container, docker-network

I want to get docker host machine ip address and interface names i.e ifconfig of docker host machine. instead im getting docker container ip address on doing ifconfig in docker container.

It would be great if someone tell me to fetch ip address of docker host machine from a docker container.

i have tried doing ifconfig dockerhostname,
as a result i get error
dockerhostmachi: error fetching interface information: Device not found

This is my dockerfile

FROM ubuntu:14.04

## Install dependencies

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    python-enum \
    apache2    \
    libapache2-mod-wsgi  \
    python-pip \
    python-qt4

```
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/log/apache2/error.log
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/log/apache2/access.log
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/run/apache2/
```

RUN a2enmod wsgi

i need to get ifconfig result for docker host machine from a docker container or when i run docker image.

Comment: If you're building a graphical application that needs host-level configuration details, you will find it vastly easier to run without Docker.  Details of the host network are _intentionally_ hidden from your container, _by design_; running graphical applications also involves jumping through several hoops with subtle failure modes.

Comment: I am using docker to bind all the dependencies  ,so that i can load docker image on another machine and  without internet ill be able to deploy the application and its dependencies. and coming to docker host machine ip, i am able to ping to it from container but not able get details of interfaces and ip address of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to above question is follows .

1. METHOD :you can create your own network and communicate with it.

$ sudo docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.10.0/24      --gateway=192.168.10.1 doc1net
                              or
$ sudo docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=10.45.0.0/24 --gateway=10.45.0.0 doc1net

Here sub-net and gateway can be your own network address and doc1net is a my network name.

2 METHOD

While running the docker connect with your network host.

$ sudo docker network ls
gives you list of your networks.

$ sudo docker run -it --network=host myimage
Here myimage is name of the image i have created

2nd method worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you run docker image/container you can specify an environment variable using -e parameter. Do it maybe like:
    docker run -e ip=docker_host_ip ...

then it should be available on container side as environment variable.

https://medium.com/the-code-review/top-10-docker-run-command-options-you-cant-live-without-a-reference-d256834e86c1